# How can you simulate an array with two unbounded stacks and a small amount of memory?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was just going through past slides of one of the courses being offered in my University.

Here is the slide which mentions this question: http://www.cse.psu.edu/~asmith/courses/cse565/F10/www/lec-notes/CSE565-F10-Lec-03.pptx.pdf

However, I am not sure if I correctly understand the question and am also thus clueless on the solution.

Any pointers on what the problem is and how to think about it?

Answer (score 2):

To simulate an array you need to allow for indexed lookup.

Insert:

Given 2 unbounded stacks, call them foo and bar, initially you can keep inserting to foo.

Lookup:

When the user tries to lookup an element, you simply pop the stack.size - index times into the bar. The next pop will give you the element user is looking for. However at this point you can do a peek instead of a pop because the array does not delete its elements on lookup.

Now you can either push all the elements back onto foo from bar or push the rest of the elements from bar onto foo. But in the latter case, you need to reverse you indexing.

Delete:

To implement a delete you can simply mark the element as deleted. If the user ever tries to inserting an element at that index you can pop and push the new element. Whereas on lookup you should return whatever represents an empty index.

Answer (score 2):

The primary tasks:

- appending
- removal
- insertion
- indexed lookup

Lets call the two stacks "S1" and "S2"

**Appending**

to append something, pop everything from S2, pushing them onto S1, then push the new value onto S1

**Pop**

Pop everything from S2, pushing them onto S1, then pop the last item on S1

**Indexed removal**

Pop everything from S2 onto S1.  Pop the first `i` items from S1 into S2.  Pop the top off of S1.

**insertion**

To insert at index `i` (0 based), pop everything off of S1 into S2, then pop the first `i` items off of S2 and push them back onto S1.  Now push your value onto S1.

**indexed lookup**

Pop everything off of S2 and push them onto S1.  Now pop the first `i` items off of S1 and push them into S2.  The item you are looking for should be the top item on S1.

**Note**

the Pop-everything and push onto another process can be dramatically simplified by keeping track of how many items there are total, and where you are currently.  If you keep track of these two (or any other numbers that reflect these), then you can calculate exactly how many you need to transfer instead of counting from the beginning.

This implementation isn't as much an "array" implementation as much as a "list" implementation.  It's essentially a simplified linked-list (the next node is just under the current node, the previous node is on the top of the other stack) where the only data you have is the current node.

Comment: In case of removal if you pop the item it would screw up your current index. Isn't it better it just mark it as deleted and pop it if that index position is replaced by another value.

Comment: Well, not really.  You'd just have to decrease your total by 1 and your current index by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a bogo-index and current value in memory, values at lower indices in one stack and values at higher indices in another.  To go to another index, keep popping from the appropriate stack and pushing the current value to the other, and decrement/increment the bogo-index until it's  where you want.  You can wrap it up with bounds checks if you like.